# Discord bot issue with getting user roles check

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So im doing a mute function where i add a muted role based on the channel they are muted from, my issue here is that it actually refuses to get the guild member by id, and ends up with hasRole erroring out because discordMember is undefined when trying with id, if i use mention way no problem it works as intended.

Anyone got a surgestion to fix this.

```
const discordMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
const channelName = message.mentions.channels.first()

var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == channelName.name + "-mute");
var hasRole = discordMember.roles.cache.has(role.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Closing since original issue was fixed.